# SQL Server 2005 Xml Parameter Causing Timeout?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, parameters

I'm trying to send a XML of aproximately 1MB as XML parameter in a Stored Procedure, but always the connection returns timeout.

Anyone knows what's the size limit for the XML type?

---

Environment:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express
- .NET Framework 2.0
- C#

---

C# Code:

```
using (SqlCommand commandSave = new SqlCommand("SaveScanning", this.DatabaseConnection))
{
    commandSave.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter scanningData = new SqlParameter("ScanningData", System.Data.SqlDbType.Xml);
    scanningData.Value = new SqlXml(new XmlTextReader(**HEREISTHEXMLSTRING**, XmlNodeType.Document, null));
    commandSave.Parameters.Add(scanningData);

    commandSave.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

SQL Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveScanning]
(
    @ScanningData XML
)
AS
BEGIN
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: When a lower XML content is passed, it works normally. (100kb)

Comment: size limit is 2gb of binary xml which is generally more compact than a textual representation of xml (e.g. qnames are tokenized in binary xml)

Comment: I guess that the problem is on SQL Server. When i'm trying to send a big XML and try to INSERT the data in a TABLE from SELECT clause, the problem occurs. When just the SELECT from XML is used, the problem doesn't occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution:

The OPENXML "function" to read XML it's so far the best way.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertXMLData
(
    @XMLDoc XML
)
AS
```

---

Faster way:

```
DECLARE @handle INT

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT, @XMLDoc

INSERT INTO TestTable
SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@handle, '/authors', 2) WITH 
  (au_id INT,
   au_lname VARCHAR(20),
   au_fname VARCHAR(20)
  )
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @handle
```

Very slow way:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable
SELECT
    x.item.value('@au_id', 'INT') AS au_id,
    x.item.value('@au_lname', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS au_lname
    x.item.value('@au_fname', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS au_fname
FROM
    @XMLDoc.nodes('/authors') x(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

2 GB is the max size for the XML data type.  I've done XML Parameters with 20MB worth of text that result in 1000 rows inserted and this takes a quad xeon box that averages 500 user spids w/ connection pooling that sits around 25% cpu, w/ 16 GB of ram about 10 seconds.

Edit:

What XML method are you using with your SQL Select that is having the issue?

XQuery?
XPath?
Open XML?

If you could provide more of your T-SQL it would help.

Comment: That's the problem... I'm trying to insert 5000 records from a Select in XML... More than 1000 records and SQL Server returns timeout...

Comment: 5000 records is what size in XML text?  The 1000 records I mentioned earlier was going into a table with about 50 columns made up of lots of varchar(50).  If your 5000 records is only 5 columns wide that is nothing.  When I was testing my initial XML import I recall testing up to 20,000 records which was over 400MB of xml text and IIRC it took around 2.5-3 min to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Timeout means the query is taking too long, not that the parameter is too large.

Of course, it's possible that your query takes too long *because* the parameter is too large. Try the same query, with the same parameter, in SQL Server Management Studio (download the version for Express).

Comment: I've tried in SQL Server Management Studio and the process performed in just 2 seconds...